# Nautilus crashes accessing a certain folder

Tags: nautilus

Nautilus exits when I try to access a certain folder. This is what it says when started from the command line:

```
    user@Computer:~/Dokumente/Briefe$ nautilus ./
    Initializing Arronax v0.05...
    sys:1: Warning: g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
    Syntax Warning: May not be a PDF file (continuing anyway)
    Syntax Error: Couldn't find trailer dictionary
    Syntax Error: Couldn't read xref table
    Error loading document: File type Einfaches Textdokument (text/plain) is not supported
    sys:1: Warning: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
    Speicherzugriffsfehler (Speicherabzug geschrieben)
    user@Computer:~/Dokumente/Briefe$
```

I'm on ubuntu 13.10 with gnome-shell classic. I followed some advice from other posts, e.g. removed ubuntu one, ran `sudo apt-get purge nautilus-open-terminal` and restarted the computer, but the error remains.

Comment: Can you try moving files and see if a specific file or type is causing it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  Removing a file from the affected folder resulting in nautilus crashing whatever folder I tried to open.

The only thing I found that fixed it was completely removing nautilus:

```
sudo apt-get  purge nautilus
```

and then reinstalling it:

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus
```

Answer (score 0):

What could help is resetting the ownership of configuration files.
First test if this will help you, by running nautilus as root:

```
sudo nautilus
```

If it then works, hen reset the ownership of the config-files in your home-dir:

```
sudo chown -hR <username>:<username> ~/.*
```