# Nautilus crashes

Tags: nautilus

Every time I try to open any folder the window pops up and disappear. I tried using nautilus command in terminal and it printed following message

```
Initializing nautilus-open-terminal extension
sys:1: Warning: g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Syntax Warning: May not be a PDF file (continuing anyway)
Syntax Error: Couldn't find trailer dictionary
Syntax Error: Couldn't read xref table
Error loading document: File type plain text document (text/plain) is not supported

(nautilus:7376): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_loader_close: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF_LOADER (loader)' failed

(nautilus:7376): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_loader_get_pixbuf: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF_LOADER (loader)' failed
sys:1: Warning: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

This started to happen when I tried to open a pdf downloaded using chrome. (Now that file is not there)

Answer (score 1):

Removing and re-installing nautilus fixed the problem as mentioned in ["Nautilus crashes accessing a certain folder"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/446401/nautilus-crashes-accessing-a-certain-folder?rq=1)